# How to call a method while overriding it

Tags: python, methods, overriding, pycharm, abstract

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
    class AbstractClass(object):
        __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

        @abstractmethod
        def foo(self):
            pass

    class A(AbstractClass):
        def __init__():
            super().__init__()

        def foo(self):
            //Logic

    class B(A):
        def __init__():
            super().__init__()
```

I want to use foo as it is implemented in A, so I cannot override it in B.
Using B.foo() works, but I still get the warning from PyCharm:

> "Class B must implement all abstract methods"

Do I have to override a method that already overrides an abstract method? How do I override it without losing the implementation? Just copy the method to the sub class?

Comment: I see you use Python 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just going to ask this question when I suddenly had an idea how it could work. I thought "how I can call a method after I just overrode it?"
After some thought I finally figured it out.

Call the overridden method from the super class while overriding it in the sub class:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__():
        super().__init__()

    def foo(self):
        super().foo()
```

This works because a supertypes method must work with its subtypes without further implementation provided. After I figured it out it just seems so logical.

This might be useful for people who are just figuring out how inheritance works.

Comment: I am not sure what your final goal is, but yes, with super you can call the one defined in the superclass. Python looks in the namespace of the superclasses when you refer to a name through `self` if the name is not present in the object's namespace, so in case you do not need to override `foo` specifically, in B just use `self.foo()` to call the one defined in `A`.